# Pandas read_table reads mixed type reading string as hexadecimal

Tags: parsing, pandas, dataframe

I have this code:

[Link to code and data on GitHub](https://github.com/RichardAfolabi/Sandbox-for-stuffs/blob/master/demo.ipynb).

```
col_names = {'age_code':'str', 'los_code':'str', 'race_code':'str'}
injuries = pd.read_table(some_url, dtype=col_names)
```

The `los_code`, `age_code` and `race_code` have another table with the codes. For example `race_code` is:

```
  race_code                          race_text
0      0000                          All races
1      1XXX                White, non-Hispanic
2      2XXX                Black, non-Hispanic
3      3XXX                           Hispanic
4      4XXX          Asian or Pacific Islander
5      5XXX  American Indian or Alaskan Native
6      NRXX                       Not reported
```

After reading, all these threes columns have `NaN` entries except when the code is `0000`. If the column entry is any of `1XXX` to `NRXX`, the entry becomes `NaN`.

It appears pandas is reading the column as `int` because of the `0000` entries but get confused after reading entries with the `X` (maybe confusing it for hexadecimal)

How can I force pandas to read these entries as string.

Besides I also get the error:

> DtypeWarning: Columns (1,4,5,6,7,8,9) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
>     interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `'object'` instead of `'str'`.

```
col_names = {'age_code':'object', 'los_code':'object', 'race_code':'object'}
```

Consider using something like `col_dtypes` instead of `col_names` as variable name. Also consider reading the [Pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/) to find answers to such questions.

---

Ps. That's a warning, not an error you are getting.

---

**EDIT**

Ok, I looked at your data and code. Here is a screen snip when I opened your table in the humble MS Excel. Can you show me where the values for age_code, race_code and los_code are? Because if there is no data in the columns, Pandas will insert NaN there. Also note the summary statistics produced by Excel in the bottom right corner of the screen snip. Average = 0, Min = 0, Max = 0, Sum = 0, Count = 410. There are 410 readings, and all are zeros. I selected all rows in the three columns of interest. The data is missing in the table you are reading.

And then, there doesn't seem to be a problem reading the tables of age_code, race_code and los_code individually. Lastly, take the tip from the warning, and pass `low_memory=False` in your `pd.read_table()`, instead of `dtype=col_names`.

[image: Excel screen snip]

I consider your question answered, because the missing values are in your data. They are not caused by Pandas, or a result of your code.

Comment: Indeed I've tried that before I asked the question but did not work. I've edited the question to include link to the code on GitHub.

Comment: Interesting. Because once you pass `dtype` kwarg, Pandas should only use that and typecast everything in that format. Let me run some tests tomorrow, and update answer accordingly.

Comment: Check out the edits in the answer. The problem is in your data, not your code or Pandas. This question is answered.

Comment: Thanks for checking Kartik